# running multiple instances of Tomcat in spring boot?

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, spring-boot

my application has 2 REST API Controller (from different projects)  and one has to call the other controller and as i see it either i  run one project on different machine (this is slow , i am dependent on other person).
or if somehow i can run multiple instances of tomcat.

I searched and found defining **VM Argument**  **"-Dserver.port=8090"** and then **"-Dserver.port=8091"** in another will work.

Well this worked , i was able to start them but i could not debug it in debug mode. it was showing thread stack but it was not displaying actually code.
It sound strange but it happened.

Please help if you have faced same situation. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't these two controllers be running in same DispatcherServlet?

Comment: @Ikrnac we have to host them on different servers.

Comment: If you have to VMs you'll also need two debug ports and settings – at least if you run them on the same machine.

Answer (score 4):

This is not good idea. I suggest to avoid this direction completely. If you have two Spring Boot projects, run them as two separate processes on two different embedded tomcats.

Spring Boot doesn't care if you run them on same machine if your externalize configs properly.

Comment: This is what i am doing, i am running my server 2 times one with port 8090 and once with 8091 but it do not solve my purpose. i am not able to debug with this method.

Comment: You are trying to debug them both at the same time? I didn't try it but can imagine it would work in Eclipse.

Comment: BTW, have you heart about Remote Debugging via JMX? That would be the option.

Comment: @Ikmac i will try that option and will come back to you.